# How to collect a SQL request from an ArrayList

Tags: java, sql

I have an arrayList like that:

```
    List<String> list = new  ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
```

And i want to insert this information in a SQL query string like that :

```
AND Column_X in ('A' ,'B' , 'C')
```

Can you help me ?

edited:

Thank you :)
I found other solution, this is what i want :

```
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    String sqlStr= "";
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        sqlStr+= "'"+iterator.next()+"'";
        if(iterator.hasNext()) sqlStr+= ',';
    }
    System.out.println(sqlStr);
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you using an ORM?  Are you just using straight up `SqlCommand`s?  Need more context.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? getting the sql code from arraylist instead of writing it every time you need ?

Comment: No, I'm using the Native Java connection without any ORM

Comment: You can do that but that will be very slow if the list is too big. Remember that every time you concatenate two strings in java you’re really destroying the original string and creating a new one. Try this simple example:
String str = "";
for(int i = 0; i< 10000; i++) str += i;
System.out.println(str);

efficient method:

StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
for(int i = 0; i< 10000; i++) str.append(i);
System.out.println(str.toString());

Best Regards

Comment: in my case i don't have a lot of data, but thanks @Deceiver for your remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Connection c = ...
Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE Column_X IN ('";
for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   if(i > 0) {
      sql += ",'"
   }
   sql += list.get(i) + "'";
}
sql += ")";
ResultSet r = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a StringBuilder - iterate over the list yourself, constructing a "," delimited string. Or use a useful API like `StringUtils.join()` from the apache commons project that already does that.
Keep in mind that parameters need to be properly escaped to avoid syntax errors, or worse, SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

You could write a utility method like this:

```
public static String getCommaSeparatedTexts(List<String> texts){
   final StringBuilder commaSeparatedTextBuilder = new StringBuilder("'");
   for (final String text : texts.values()) {
      commaSeparatedTextBuilder.append(text);
      commaSeparatedTextBuilder.append(',');
   }

   final int length = commaSeparatedTextBuilder.length();
   commaSeparatedTextBuilder.setLength(length - 1);

   return commaSeparatedTextBuilder.toString();
}
```

But be careful, when the returned String is empty, your SQL statement will fail.

Comment: this is the function that i want ;)
 private String arrayListToSQL(List<String> list){
  Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
     String sqlStr= "";
     while (iterator.hasNext()){
         sqlStr+= "'"+iterator.next()+"'";
         if(iterator.hasNext()) sqlStr+= ',';
     }
     return sqlStr;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite `toString` method of arrayList and create a string in the form which you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`list.toString()` gives you `[A, B, C]`.  You have to ignore `[`, `]` and space from it.

`AND Column_X in ("'"+(list.toString().substring(1,list.toString().length()-1)).toString().replaceAll(",", "','").replaceAll(" ","")+"'")`